# FCM notification not received when app is on Active Tab- NextJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, next.js

I'm trying to integrate FCM in to my NextJs Application.I am sending a push notification from Postman. i got the notification when i minimize my chrome browser.but not when it is on active.

As i know it should fire `onMessage` event when browser is on active.but my `onMessage` is not fired when i send notification.

**postman request**

```
 {
        "to" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
       "data": {
            "notification": {
            "title": "Hello",
            "body": "world"
        }  
    }
    }
```

**main.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { requestFirebaseNotificationPermission, onMessageListener } from './../../firebaseInit'

const Main = () => {

    useEffect(() => {

        requestFirebaseNotificationPermission()
            .then((firebaseToken) => {
                console.log("fcm -->", firebaseToken);
                localStorage.setItem("fcm_token", firebaseToken)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("fcm error -->", err)
                return err;
            });

        function getMessage() {
            const messaging = firebase.messaging();
            messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
                console.log('foreground ', payload)
            }
            );
        }
        getMessage();
    })

    return (
        <div>
            ...........
        </div>)
}

export default Main;
```

**firebaseInit.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';
let messaging = null;
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxx"
};

if (typeof self !== 'undefined') {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    messaging = firebase.messaging();
}

export const requestFirebaseNotificationPermission = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        messaging
            .requestPermission()
            .then(() => messaging.getToken())
            .then((firebaseToken) => {
                resolve(firebaseToken);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
```